# When the screen rotation changes in the android application, a margin occurs on the starting side

Tags: android, layout, orientation, margin, fullscreen

A few commits were working fine before, both in portrait mode and in landscape mode, the application was working as fullscreen, but now when I put it in landscape mode, I noticed that it gives a margin from the head or the last part of the screen, and I don't think this margin is due to my layout because the background color of the part given margin is not even defined in my theme file. I have no idea when I didn't notice when the problem started.

[image: 1]

There is my mainactivity layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"`
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>

--MANIFEST--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ui.PopcornApplication"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Popcorn"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Popcorn"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>   

--THENE--

<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Popcorn" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary"> @color/royalBlue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_bg</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/royalBlue</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" >@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>


    <style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:background">#393636</item>
    </style>
    
    <style name="ratingBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small">
        <item name="android:progressTint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:progressBackgroundTint">@color/white</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

End i said it was working as expected older commits but i checkout the commits where orientation was working now that commits even doesnt work its same as current one. I dont know what i did can it be a phone problem. The last thing i did i made a release apk version and some proguard rules

Comment: Does your device have a camera cutout on that side of the device? Is your activity set up to go [edge to edge](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge)?

Comment: Yes there is a camera cutout that side my activity setup edge to edge